# Localization of strings in C# in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, localization

We've had a requirement come out of the blue where we need to localize string at sent from the WCF service. The challenge is that we have a whole bunch of data model objects that we return from the service, there objects have strings as the data members. Is there some way we can localize these strings in a central place rather than localize each of these strings individually?

Comment: Have you considered using string resources?

Comment: I already have the string resources, but I am looking for a way to localize all strings in a central place rather than localizing them individually.

Comment: What do you consider not central with string resources? You have one place where all your string resources are stored...

Comment: Eg. my WCF service returns an object called WorldLocation with the following string fields which need to be localized - name, type, country and string fields - person are  not be localized
To localize, each time the set of these fields is called I need to localize from the resouce bundle.
Instead doing the localization on each set, is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure, what you're understanding under 'localize these strings in a central place'. I think, you have the following options.

1. Create a library containing the localization strings in the resource dictionaries. It could be used by the wcf service and the frontend you are implementing. Then you could pass the resource keys from WCF service.
   This works only well, if you don't want to publish you the WCF service. Advantage lies in the single point of change during the development One major problem here is to distinguish between resource keys and "normal string values", which don't need to be interpreted. I would use this option only in case of few strings.
2. When requesting the WCF service pass a `CultureInfo` e.g. `en-GB, de-DE, ...` and let the service return the strings in the correct culture. If a culture is not supported, return the string in the fallback culture. In this option you're relatively free how you implement the localization. A resource dictionary or extra tables in the database both are imaginable solutions. Big advantage compared to option 1, you don't need to interpret the returned strings in the frontend.

I hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Is there some way I can do this via annotations - at a central place; eg - 
DataObject obj = ProcessObject();
DataObject locObj = LocalizeObject(obj, locale);

The LocalizeObject() is able to do the localization by fields that are annotated.